# Combining diacritics not combining visually

Tags: faces, fonts, unicode

The first two characters in the left buffer are `LATIN SMALL LETTER A` and `COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT`. Together they should display as `â`, just like `LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX`, `â`.

However, as you can see, the circumflex is appearing next to the `a`, not above it.

The screenshot is from GNU Emacs 26.1, `emacs -Q` on Ubuntu 18.04. The characters display correctly in other applications. What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Do those other applications just change the visual appearance, or do they also compose the two characters into the single character â?

Comment: @RobertPluim I'm not sure how to diagnose between the two options you're suggesting. If I paste `â` into gedit, the hat is on top. If I copy it from gedit and paste it back into emacs, the hat moves to the right.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question: gedit is visually composing the characters, but not combining them into the single character LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX.

Comment: I asked emacs-devel about this, and Eli Zaretskii helpfully pointed out that emacs will only do this combining if you're using a font that supports both 'a' and COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT. In your case the two fonts are different. Would you know which font gedit is using? (I just tried gedit here with "Droid Sans Mono", and it display the two characters separately).

Comment: @RobertPluim Ah, looks like gedit was using DejaVu. So I tried `(set-frame-font "-PfEd-DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline-normal-normal-normal-*-42-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1")` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having this problem too, and it has nothing to do with the fonts: Unicode fonts that displayed combined characters correctly in gnu emacs 25, now display incorrectly in gnu emacs 26, while displaying correctly in other applications. I think this is a bug in emacs 26, but I'm not sure how to report it.

Comment: @MayerGoldberg `M-x report-emacs-bug` perhaps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For emacs to be able to combine successive characters, you need to be using a font that has support for both of the characters. As per the comments, in your case that was 'DejaVu Sans Mono'.